# safely install opensource or proprietary amd driver in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, amd-graphics, fglrx, hybrid-graphics

My system (hp i3) has hybrid graphics Intel/AMD (`R5 M330`). Yesterday I tried installing ubuntu `16.04` (using a bootable drive on windows installed drive, I erased everything). But after the first complete `sudo apt-get install update && upgrade` I rebooted the system, Afterwards, it did not boot and showed `low graphics error` dialogue and `VCE error (-22)`+ black screen. From that time till now, I googled many sites and have tried many things.

1. Tried using the proprietary `fglrx` driver from `Additional Driver` option in `Ubuntu` (did not work,it got installed but purple screen freeze atfer next reboot).
2. Removed `16.04` and installed `14.04` and tried the same thing.(Did not work again).
3. In `14.04` I tried installing catalyst drivers from AMD website using GUI (it was not showing the texts in the GUI, but somehow I managed to follow using screenshots). But it did not work. It showed "`remove already installed` `fglrx`". But I never installed anything related to `fglrx` before. However, I still executed few commands to remove the `fglrx*`.Nop, it still did not work. I tried using the command line as well, nothing worked (it showed some error like `./amd_gpu .. no adaptor` (I don't remember exactly) in the fglrx.log file).
4. Anything I tried installing related to AMD graphics resulted in the purple screen in the next reboot. I also executed many commands related to Xorg server etc. (mentioned in lots of sites, most of them I could not understand ). But nothing helped. All ended up in frozen black or purple screen.
5. So, I made a fresh install (`14.04`) again and I have not yet installed anything (apart from few `gcc` tools). I made few reboot and it is working fine.

I might not have executed the correct commands or might be doing wrong in all of my above tries. But I have found a lot of online resources and I am confused what to do next :(.  I don't play any high-end game or don't do any intensive computation work (mostly do programming in `c/c++/python`). So I think avoiding `fglrx` is ok for me (please suggest).Currently, the Ubuntu software update dialogue box shows ' 250 +' `MB` pending and it shows some `server-xorg AMD` packages. I have not updated those yet (simply I don't want to repair/reinstall the purple screen death loop again).

I am pasting few outputs here (You may ask for other outputs in the comment section, I don't know what are the relevant output to present my situation)

```
 $> lspci -nn | grep ATI
0d:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] [1002:6660] (rev ff)


$> lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'
 Kernel driver in use: i915


$> sudo lshw -c video
 *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:7000(size=64)
 $> lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 80c2
  Kernel driver in use: i915
  00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
  --
  0d:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] (rev ff)
  Kernel driver in use: radeon
  13:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 804c
```

Please suggest what should I do now?

1. Should I upgrade the pending xserver-xorg packages showing in ubuntu software updater?
2. Is my system currently using some opensource drivers?
3. How to install (any possible working method) opensource AMD drivers for my system (`intel/amd` hybrid `M5 330`), such that the system can render the minimal stuff when needed. If this is not requiredat all, please suggest.
4. If there is a safe way to install some proprietary driver like (catalyst or crimson) in my system?

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank You.

****update****

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:0d:00.0 ==
model    : Sun XT [Radeon HD 8600M Series]
vendor   : Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
modalias : pci:v00001002d00006660sv0000103Csd000080C2bc03sc80i00
driver   : fglrx - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-ati - distro free builtin recommended
driver   : fglrx-updates - distro non-free
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you'd like to know? We can help you solve specific problems, e. g. related to the installation of the Radeon/fglrx/AMDGPU driver in Ubuntu 14.04/16.04 but we cannot decide for you where you should go from here. Please [edit] your question and highlight which problem you'd like to solve. You can even [open additional questions](/questions/new) for other possible roads to a solution.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks. Sure, I would be happy to `open additional question`. For now, I want to know the way to use the opensource AMD drivers for my M330 graphics card, such that it can support the minimal rendering.  Should  I upgrade the pending xserver-xorg packages from ubuntu software updater?  Is my system currently using some opensource drivers?

Comment: Sir, I have edited the post and added few QS. I would be happy to have any positive suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! That's better. I don't know anything about AMD or hybrid graphics but I'm sure the changes will make it much easier to answer by someone who does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to show all the proprietary drivers that are available to be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories and are compatible with your hardware, open the terminal and type:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Wait at least one minute for the command to scan your computer and generate the list of drivers. The output of this command will be a list of the package names and short descriptions of the available drivers. In addition to showing a list of the available drivers, the above command will often also identify the recommended proprietary driver(s) for your system.

If you visit the official AMD website you will often see that the latest version of the proprietary graphics driver for your GPU is a little bit more up-to-date than the version of the same graphics driver that is available from the default Ubuntu repositories. Don't worry about this, because if the difference between version numbers of the two proprietary graphics drivers is small, then you will get similar performance by using either of the two drivers. If you install a graphics driver from the default Ubuntu repositories, you will also get automatic updates to the driver which are sometimes linked to kernel updates.

`ubuntu-drivers devices` won't give accurate results if you already have a proprietary graphics driver installed. It will often show the proprietary graphics driver that is currently installed as the recommended driver, so for best results uninstall the proprietary graphics driver (if one is installed) and reboot before running `ubuntu-drivers devices`

The results of `ubuntu-drivers devices` are:

```
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-ati - distro free builtin recommended
```

Using the built-in open source `xserver-xorg-video-ati` package will future-proof your Ubuntu at least up to Ubuntu 18.04, because the default repositories of Ubuntu 16.04 and later do not include any proprietary drivers for AMD graphics.

Comment: Thanks.I updated the post. I removed `fglrx*` before running `ubuntu-drivers devices`. It means the opensource driver is installed right?

Comment: To be sure that Ubuntu is not still  using fglrx reboot Ubuntu before running `ubuntu-drivers devices`